# How is FastCGI implemented under Windows?

Tags: windows, fastcgi, specifications

The official FastCGI documentation says that `stdin` is repurposed as a listening socket when a FastCGI module is started. That's great on Linux, where `stdin` and sockets are all `int`s, but I don't think it could it work on Windows, where `stdin` is a `FILE*`, and a socket is a `HANDLE`.

Since Windows servers *do* support FastCGI, someone has either found a way to make them compatible, or redefined the system for that OS. My Google-fu doesn't seem to be up to locating *how* though. Where can I find documentation on it?

Comment: Wikipedia article mentions "Unix domain socket, a named pipe, or a Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) connection".

Comment: All of those would be `int`s under Linux (or UNIX, or MacOSX), but `HANDLE`s under Windows (where they can be done at all). I can believe that Windows FastCGI systems would use pipes or TCP connections, but how would that be passed to the FastCGI program? The `stdin` method, repurposing `int(0)`, wouldn't work for them. That's what I'm asking for documentation on.

Comment: I apparently still don't see the problem. In C++ we are given a `streambuf`, so it shouldn't matter how it's implemented inside. Could you describe the implementation in more detail so that the problem becomes clearer?

Comment: That's what I'm asking for -- the implementation. How is the `streambuf` passed to a FastCGI program running under Windows? The method outlined in the spec won't work under Windows, but FastCGI programs have been adapted to work under Windows -- I'm trying to figure out how, preferably with actual documentation on the method used.

Comment: Maybe the spec is incorrect. You get `streambuf`, but you don't get `stdin`.

Comment: I've successfully implemented it under Linux, so the spec is correct there.

Comment: Let's assume you implementation talks with web server over TCP/IP. Your implemenetation gets an array of bytes, and passes this array to client app with `streambuf`. I see no problem doing this in Windows too.

Comment: Yes, that's no problem. The problem comes before that part: the method that the spec outlines for passing the listen socket to the FastCGI handler program would not work under Windows, to the best of my knowledge. I'm trying to determine how Windows servers change that part of the spec to make it work on that OS.

Answer (score 0):

FastCGI defines only the message exchange protocol, but people behind FastCGI also provide one implementation of that protocol for C++. In this implementation your app must use provided `FCGX_Request` object to rewire three provided `FCGX_Stream` objects to the usual ones (cin, cout, cerr). But I suspect that you don't have to rewire the streams, and can use them directly. Check out this [FastCGI Hello World](http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/) to see how it's done.

So, your app does not see `HANDLE` or `FILE*`. It sees instead `fcgi_streambuf`, which inherits from `std::streambuf`. The way the previously mentioned protocol is implemented is just a detail that you're not supposed to be concerned with. The implementation gets hold of a stream of bytes and provides it to the app, and also the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a detail I very much need, as I'm writing my own FastCGI library. :-) As I understand it, the original FastCGI library doesn't support Windows (which makes sense, due to the problem I outlined in the question).